# "Нейронная сеть хорошо обучилась(,) и довольно быстро". Нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Нужна ли запятая в следующем предложении?
**Нейронная сеть хорошо обучилась(,) и довольно быстро.**

Если поменять члены предложения местами, то запятая точно не нужна:
**Нейронная сеть обучилась хорошо и довольно быстро.**
Меня это смущает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В предложении **Нейронная сеть хорошо обучилась(,) и довольно быстро** запятая нужна. Это присоединительный член предложения.

Дело в том, что при таком порядке слов однородными членами воспринимаются глагол и наречное словосочетание **довольно быстро.** Это неправильно. Однородные члены обычно выражаются одной и той же частью речи, относятся к одному и тому же члену предложения и отвечают на один и тот же вопрос.

Во втором предложении союз **и** связывает однородные члены предложения, поэтому запятая не нужна.